# Translate strings in out-of-project-dir apps (ej. django-rest-framework)

Tags: django

Assume I install `djangorestframework` app in my project. This application has many translatable strings (most of them, if not all, are for API errors). DRF is at version 3+, while Django==1.7.

When I generate the translated messages (with makemessages) I use the following command:

```
python ./manage.py makemessages -l es
```

I get my .po files being generated, but `rest_framework` (application package for the Django REST Framework library) does not have any translation files. In this way, I force it to have the to-translate strings being also generated using the following method:

- Create a symbolic link, in my project directory, to the `rest_framework` package/directory.
- `python ./manage.py makemessages -l es --symlinks`
- Remove the symbolic link. The translatable strings from django-rest-framework are now included in my django.po files.

But this method is ugly for me.

How can I include such strings to be added to my django.po file without manually adding them and without using the method I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [version 3.1](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.1-announcement/#internationalization), DRF has translations of popular languages, including ES. [Full list](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/tree/master/rest_framework/locale)

If your target lang is not in the list, I suggest you to contribute translations into DRF. [How to add](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/internationalization/#adding-new-translations)

**Update:**
Django searches for translation strings under current working folder (`"."`). As far as I know, symbolic link (your solution) is the only way to let `makemessages` access 3rd party packages that outside your project. Maybe you can suggest Django team to implement a feature which allows `makemessages` to seek through `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Note that this is new, introduced in 3.1.

Comment: Cool! Did not check 3.1 version :D. But what about other -potentially- third party libraries? (i.e. if DRF was not the case but another set of libraries). Have my upvote for pointing me to 3.1 and i18n improvements :)

Comment: @LuisMasuelli, as far as I know, for 3rd party no better solution than yours. Added some update in my answer